# How to select all inactive divs for a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I'm just learning jQuery, and I'm trying to write a little script. To sum up the basic HTML code:

```
<ul class="boxes">
<li id="box1">1</li>
<li id="box2">2</li>
<li id="box3">3</li>
</ul>
```

I'm then using jQuery to create a hover effect of the active element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#box2').hover(function(){
  // In
  $(this).text('IN')
}, function(){
  // Out
  $(this).text('OUT')
})
```

What I want to add is that all the other li elements that aren't hovered, fade away. I'm wondering if there is an opposite to $(this) that targets all the non-hovered 'li' in the 'ul' class "boxes".

Thanks to anyone that can help me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite of `this` could be [.not(this)](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('.boxes li').not(this).fadeOut();
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq4zA/).

Comment: without `stop()` you can get some strange results rapidly hovering/leaving the item.

Comment: Hi scessor, thanks for this, I can see how it works now and have got it working as I wanted. :)

Comment: @Dutchie432: This behaviour will be visible with a high duration-parameter of the fadeIn and fadeOut method (like in your example); in my example this value is to low (so I save this command).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.boxes li').hover(function(){
        $('.boxes li').not(this).fadeOut();
    }, function(){
        $('.boxes li').not(this).fadeIn();
    })
});
```

Comment: without `stop()` you can get some strange results rapidly hovering/leaving the item.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little sample of what I think you are trying to accomplish.

The key is, while using unique `id` attribute values like you're doing, to use a common class (in this case, `box`).

**WORKING DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gkkta/3/**

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
    $('.box').stop().fadeTo(500, .5);
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(1000, 1.0);
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(500, .5);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice of using a class. :)

Answer (score 0):

the other way is to `fadeout` `all` and the `fadein` `this`

```
$('#box2').hover(function(){
      $('.boxes > li').fadeTo(100,.25);
      $(this).text('IN').fadeTo(100,1);
    }, function(){
     $('.boxes > li').fadeTo(100,1);
     $(this).text('OUT');
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/n2Znw/1/